# Pause execution of a function using a coroutine untiy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to implement behaviour trees in untiy and right now i am using a Tick() function for each Node/Composite/Action

What I want to do is in a sequence,for example,is :

1. Begin the for loop itereating in the list of nodes
2. Start the tick function on the current node
3. Wait until the node tick returned Failed/Success
4. Go to the next node and continue to go to step 1

   the issue i am having is with the step 3. I am tring to accomplish this with a coroutine.

the problem is that the assertion is true, the nodeStat var is None. When the WaitFor Seconds is executed, the control gets back to `Debug.Assert(nodeStat != Status.None);` line

```
public class Sequence : Composite
{
    protected override void Start()
    {
        status = Status.Running;
    }
    Status nodeStat = Status.None;
    IEnumerator Recursive(Node nod)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log(nod + "is running");
            Status status = nod.Tick();

            Debug.Log(Time.time + " " + status);
            if (status == Status.Running)
            {
                Debug.Log("start coroutine at : " + Time.time);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
                Debug.Log("Comtinue coroutine at : " + Time.time);
            }
            else
            {

                Debug.Log("has finished coroutine");
                nodeStat = status;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    protected override Status Execute()
    {
        foreach(Node nod in ListaNoduri)
        {
            GameManager.Instance.StartCoroutine(Recursive(nod));
            Debug.Assert(nodeStat != Status.None);
            if (nodeStat == Status.Failure)
                return Status.Failure;
        }
        return Status.Success;
    }

    protected override void Exit()
    {
        base.Exit();
    }
    public override Status Tick()
    {
        //Debug.Log(status);
        return base.Tick();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use yield break to break coroutine

Comment: You aren't waiting for `Recursive` to finish in `Execute`, @NikolayGonza he is `yielding` in the `if` statement, he is using `break` to exit the `true` conditioned `while`

Comment: I also tried making the Recursive function recursive :). It had worse results than with while

Comment: Is tick using multi threading? If not then the execution won't continue in the calling  until the execution of the tick method has completed.

Comment: No, tick is not multi threading. The problem I am having is with assertion, the assertion should never reach. From the coroutine nosStat should be either Success/Failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making `Execute()` a coroutine:

```
IEnumerator Execute()
{
    foreach(Node nod in ListaNoduri)
    {
        //wait for the current node to be done before continuing
        yield return GameManager.Instance.StartCoroutine(Recursive(nod));
        Debug.Assert(nodeStat != Status.None);
        if (nodeStat == Status.Failure){
            //do something on failure 
            yield break;
        }
    }
    //do something on success
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Unfortunately, 'Execute' function mush have same return type(Status) because inherits from composite and also from Node class. In the Tick function I make use of the return type of Exit. This seems like a problem without solution to me

Comment: @nickk2002 This execute will not process any more nodes on failure, so the only `Status` the next tick will see is `Status.Success`. If you really need to, you can check `nodeStat`, it already has the status value. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but you cannot expect to get the result from Execute immediately when it might take several seconds to finish actually producing that result.

Comment: yes the function works but I am not allowed to change the return type of 'Execute function', it inherits from Node etc. and it must be as it is. What i did to work was this [link] https://ideone.com/ClvD6v. And also if you want to checkout the entire project is on github [link]  https://github.com/nickk2002/Behaviour-Trees/blob/master/BehaviourTrees/Assets/Scripts/TestAi.cs

Comment: @nickk2002 I think your problems start from the fact that `Node` is designed to work synchronously and `Sequence` is supposed to work asynchronous. Unfortunately async is "contagious" (see [Async All the Way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) ) so you would have to change Start, Execute, Tick to coroutines. Or you could go the other way and have `Execute` and `Recursive` not be coroutines but that would mean that you have to call `Tick` every frame to update. (sort of like monobehaviour update)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Corutine works similar to a thread (asynch execution).

Note that as @akaBase point on comments, the problem is that you are evaluating nodeStat just after calling the Coroutine, you aren't waiting the coroutine to finish.

So you are dispatching multiple asynch calls (one for every Node) but you aren't waiting for all of them.

One approach could be to add an event/delegate/action before your break on Recursive, where you store the result of one Node, and then evaluate on another Coroutine (that should be your current Execute), that if some delegate is false, the result is false.

Something like:

```
    private List<bool> nodeExecutionResultsList = new List<bool>();
    private Status statusResult = Status.Failure;
    private Action OnAllNodesEnd = null;

    protected override void Execute()
    {
        OnAllNodesEnd = () => { Debug.Log("Every Node Ends!"); };
        foreach (Node nod in ListaNoduri)
        {
            GameManager.Instance.StartCoroutine(Recursive(nod));            
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Recursive(Node nod)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log(nod + "is running");
            Status status = nod.Tick();

            Debug.Log(Time.time + " " + status);
            if (status == Status.Running)
            {
                Debug.Log("start coroutine at : " + Time.time);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
                Debug.Log("Comtinue coroutine at : " + Time.time);
            }
            else
            {

                Debug.Log("has finished coroutine");
                nodeStat = status;
                //Do the assert NOW, and register on the list the result
                Debug.Assert(nodeStat != Status.None);
                nodeExecutionResult.Add(nodeStat == Status.Failure);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator EvaluateAllNodes()
    {
        while(evaluating)
        {
            //there are the same number of results as nodes
            if(nodeExecutionResultsList.Count == ListaNoduri.Count)
            {
                //check if someone fails
                statusResult = (nodeExecutionResult.Contains(false)) ? Status.Failure : Status.Success;
            }
        }
        OnAllNodesEnd?.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: So my Execute function should be coroutine?. Is there a way to use sync execution? This is what I need in this case. If a make recursive calls/ use a while in the 'Recursion' function then I get an infinite loop, this was the reason behind that coroutine

Comment: Your evaluation method should be asynch, yes, but you can start all of your Coroutines with a synch method. Let me know if my code is unerstandable, I can adapt it different if something doesn't match with your current objective.

Comment: My main goal is to make the Execute function fail if one of his children fails,(the sequence composite),  so I should not proccess all nodes , then check if they failed or not. I should immediatly stop when I encounter a failure.

Comment: If you do not want to start all nodes at the same time, you should forget about Coroutines, and evaluate one after another in a synch method. But remember that will freeze the rest of your possible synch executions! You can also check instead of waiting for all the nodes results, just checking if someone added is false, then exit the evaluation routine. (replacing the nodeExecutionResultsList.Count == ListaNoduri.Count, with nodeExecutionResult.Contains(false)).

Comment: If I do use a sync function than I get into a infinite loop I guess and Unity crashes.    'code'void Recursive(Node nod)
    {
        Status status = nod.Tick();
        while(status == Status.Running)
        {
            status = nod.Tick();
        }
        nodeStat = status;
        
    }

Comment: Should see how you are implementing the sync-behaviour. Anyway, try the second method I tell you in the comment.

Comment: `void Recursive(Node nod) { 
 Status status = nod.Tick(); 
 while(status == Status.Running) { 
  status = nod.Tick(); 
 } 
 nodeStat = status; 
}` I am testing using a navmeshagent action to move to a Vector3 position. If the navmesh didn't reach the location that it returns RUNNING, if reached, returns success. This code causes infinite loop.